# AWS DMS to use CloudHSM

Tags: databases, hsm

I have a source database that need to be migrated to another one. This target will be created and integrated with CloudHSM so that the data migrated is encrypted. For migration I am planning to use AWS DMS. Both are Oracle Engine (11g). My doubts are:

1. Is this scenario possible? I mean can I use DMS to migrate from an unencrypted oracle source to CloudHSM encrypted target?
2. I see in the documents, DMS uses KMS to encrypt the data stored in the replication instance. In that case, while moving to the target database, will DMS automatically decrypt the data and then move? Or will it just move this encrypted data?

   2.a. If it is a yes for encrypted data movement, is there any way that I can bypass using KMS with the CloudHSM?